# How the values are assigned in the implementation of stack?

Tags: java, stack

I am a beginner in `Java`. So excuse me for any silly questions, I have the following code

```
void push (int item) {
        if (tos == 9)
            System.out.println("stack is full");
        else 
            stck [++tos] = item;
    }
```

Here, I cant understand how the assignment of `item` is done to `tos`.

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Do you know what `++tos` does? Do you know what `stck[0] = item;` does?

Comment: `item` isn't assigned to `tos`. It is assigned to an element of the array `stck`.

Comment: No need to downvote, `array[idx++]` is hard to get right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683786/why-does-arrayidx-a-increase-idx-once-in-java-8-but-twice-in-java-9-and-1?rq=1

Comment: I cant get the thing that "item" is not even initialized, so what is assigned to tos[0]

Comment: i got the solution of my query, actually it was about the parameters passed in the method push it wasn't related to increment or stack class