# What's the order of evaluation for this line assuming i=0 and all elements of array are initialized to 0 a[i++] = a[i++] + 2;

Tags: java, assignment-operator, post-increment

I came across this line of code in java in nutshell book and I would like to know how compiler divide this code

```
a[i++] += 2;
a[i++] = a[i++] + 2;
```

Comment: I understand that j=i++; will evaluate to j=i ; and i=i+1; 
What about these two lines

Comment: Also, depending on the exact version of java you are running, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683786/why-does-arrayidx-a-increase-idx-once-in-java-8-but-twice-in-java-9-and-1) (and [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204322)) might be of importance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =
>
> **If the left-hand operand is an array access expression** (§15.10.3), possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
>
> Otherwise, **the index subexpression of the left-hand operand array access expression is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1</sup>

I assume the order of evaluation should be as follows

```
a[i++] = a[i++] + 2;
  ^      ^ ^
  1      3 2
         ----------
             ^
             4
------
  ^
  5
--------------------
         ^
         6
```

We can prove it by running this snippet

```
int[] a = {0, 10, 0, 0};
int i = 0;
a[i++] = a[i++] + 2;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // [12, 10, 0, 0]
System.out.println(i);                  // 2
```

Comment: A (perhaps) interesting thing to point out is that both of the `i++`s are evaluated before either of the array dereferences occur. If you define `int[] a = null;`, wrap the "interesting" line in a try/catch (to catch the NPE), printing `i` after results in 2. A frankly bizarre consequence is that you can assign the array *after* you have referenced it on the LHS: `a[i++] = (a = new int[2])[i++];`, the `a` used on the LHS is the newly-assigned one.